# In the following javascript code, why the output is undefined?

Tags: javascript, return-value, settimeout

Why 'Hello World' string is not printed to console?
I expect function to return value after timer is up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var obj = {
        first(){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                return 'Hello World';
            }, 0)
        },

        second(){
            console.log(this.first());
        }
    }

    obj.second()

    </script>
```

Comment: You have to return a promise from the `first` That is the right way to do it.

Comment: return Type in call back function won't effect the method return value , You should return some value in the first method

Comment: It is as sai says, the `function(){return 'Hello World';}` callback exists in an entirely different scope to `first(){...}`, and with setTimeout being asynchronous, the call to `first()` resolves without a return statement (undefined).

Answer (score 0):

it's because `setTimeOut` is asynchronous. the `second()` function doesn't wait the callback of `setTimeOut` to finish to return the value. You should do something like:

```
var obj = {
        first(){ var _this = this;
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                _this.second('Hello World');
            }, 0);
        },

        second(text){
            console.log(text);
        }
    }

    obj.first();
```